# How to print a random int in one class that was generated in another class?

Tags: java, random

Say that I have two classes, A and B, that are in the package Sample.

In class B, I have generated a random `int x` that is either a 0 or 1. I want to print `int x` in class A. What code should I use to do this?

Here is what I have in class B so far:

```
   package Sample; 

import java.util.Random;

public class B {
    Random random = new Random();

    public void printXfromB(){
        System.out.println("What B says that 'x' is: " + getX());
    }

    public int getX() {
        int x = random.nextInt(2); //x is either 0 or 1
        return x;
    }
}
```

And this is what I have for class A:

```
package Sample; 

public class A {

    B b = new B();
    int x = b.getX(); //
    public void printXfromA(){
    System.out.println("What A says that 'x' is: " + x);
    }
}
```

The problem is, class A is generating a random number that's independent of the original `int x` in class B. How can I get class A to be dependent on class B so that they're printing out the same values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get information that needs to be shared into a scope where it may be visible. Currently your Random object and the randomly created int are buried within class B's constructor where they cannot be accessed or used anywhere else since it is *only* visible and accessible within that same constructor.

   - First off, make Random an instance field of the class: `private Random random = new Random();`
   - Next, create a method in class B that returns the value of interest, perhaps `public int getRandom() { return random.nextInt(2); }`
2. Then have class A create an instance of class B: `B b = new B();`
3. And when the random int is needed, call B's `b.getRandom()` method.

I think that the key issues that you're facing here are:

- learning about variable scope, again your data is not easily accessible outside of the method or constructor if it is declared inside of the method. Data that needs to be seen outside of a class needs to be accessible, usually via a public "getter" method. and
- Passing information between objects -- again, usually this is done by calling a public getter method.

Since this appears to be homework, I'll give these general suggestions and recommend that you try to use this to create your final code. Much luck!

---

In your changed/edited question, you're wondering why the values are different between `printXfromB` and the value obtained from `getX()`, and that is because you're re-randomizing when you get the value which changes the value. In this situation, if you need more control over randomization, then randomize in one method and extract (have a getter) in another

Comment: This was really helpful and I think I understand more. I changed it to fit more of what you're saying, but classes A and B are still sometimes outputting different numbers.

Comment: @AudraAddison: and that's because you're re-randomizing when you get the value which changes the value. In this situation, if you need more control over randomization, then randomize in one method and extract in another.

Comment: I'm still a little confused... I have the randomization in the getX() method in class B, and I extract the number by calling b.getX(), right?

Comment: did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling instance method printBfromA() from an instance of the class A:

```
public class A {

    B b = new B();

    public void printBfromA(){
      System.out.println("What A says that 'b' is: " + b.getB());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a = new A();
      a.printBfromA();
    }
}
```

You can call the printB method in B to verify that it is the same number.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class B {
    Random random = new Random();
    int b = random.nextInt(2); //b is either 0 or 1

    public void printBfromB(){
        System.out.println("What B says that 'b' is: " + b);
    }

    public int getB() {
        printBfromB();
        return b;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason I'm getting a NullPointerException

Comment: can you paste the complete stack trace